# Twitter timeline embed not displaying recent tweets correctly through iframe. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, twitter

I hope you can help me with an issue I've been facing.
A couple of weeks ago, the Twitter timeline embed on my website stopped working. It started working again a few days ago, but now the widget displays tweets from any date, not just the recent ones. I've checked, and it seems that the iframe is loading the data incorrectly. When I access the iframe's src directly, it loads correctly, but when embedded through the iframe, it displays old tweets. Any ideas on what could be causing this issue? I'd appreciate any insights or solutions you can provide. Thank you!

This is the original code provided by https://publish.twitter.com/#

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/arquitect_viva?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by arquitect_viva</a> 
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And it works perfectly
[image: Result by publish.twitter.com]

But when placing it on my website

[image]

The same problem occurs when I access the address generated by the iframe, and if I put the code of the iframe

URL: https://syndication.twitter.com/srv/timeline-profile/screen-name/arquitect_viva?creatorScreenName=arquitect_viva&dnt=false&embedId=twitter-widget-0&features=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%3D%3D&frame=false&hideBorder=false&hideFooter=false&hideHeader=false&hideScrollBar=false&lang=en&maxHeight=596.966px&origin=https%3A%2F%2Farquitecturaviva.com%2Fen&sessionId=2c445e90ceeab5df41e6db7160945615ce32d02b&showHeader=true&showReplies=false&siteScreenName=arquitect_viva&transparent=false&widgetsVersion=aaf4084522e3a%3A1674595607486

It works perfectly, but in the iframe code it doesn't

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;" src="https://syndication.twitter.com/srv/timeline-profile/screen-name/arquitect_viva?creatorScreenName=arquitect_viva&dnt=false&embedId=twitter-widget-0&features=eyJ0ZndfdGltZWxpbmVfbGlzdCI6eyJidWNrZXQiOltdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjpudWxsfSwidGZ3X2ZvbGxvd2VyX2NvdW50X3N1bnNldCI6eyJidWNrZXQiOnRydWUsInZlcnNpb24iOm51bGx9LCJ0ZndfdHdlZXRfZWRpdF9iYWNrZW5kIjp7ImJ1Y2tldCI6Im9uIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6bnVsbH0sInRmd19yZWZzcmNfc2Vzc2lvbiI6eyJidWNrZXQiOiJvbiIsInZlcnNpb24iOm51bGx9LCJ0ZndfZm9zbnJfc29mdF9pbnRlcnZlbnRpb25zX2VuYWJsZWQiOnsiYnVja2V0Ijoib24iLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjpudWxsfSwidGZ3X21peGVkX21lZGlhXzE1ODk3Ijp7ImJ1Y2tldCI6InRyZWF0bWVudCIsInZlcnNpb24iOm51bGx9LCJ0ZndfZXhwZXJpbWVudHNfY29va2llX2V4cGlyYXRpb24iOnsiYnVja2V0IjoxMjA5NjAwLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjpudWxsfSwidGZ3X3Nob3dfYmlyZHdhdGNoX3Bpdm90c19lbmFibGVkIjp7ImJ1Y2tldCI6Im9uIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6bnVsbH0sInRmd19kdXBsaWNhdGVfc2NyaWJlc190b19zZXR0aW5ncyI6eyJidWNrZXQiOiJvbiIsInZlcnNpb24iOm51bGx9LCJ0ZndfdXNlX3Byb2ZpbGVfaW1hZ2Vfc2hhcGVfZW5hYmxlZCI6eyJidWNrZXQiOiJvbiIsInZlcnNpb24iOm51bGx9LCJ0ZndfdmlkZW9faGxzX2R5bmFtaWNfbWFuaWZlc3RzXzE1MDgyIjp7ImJ1Y2tldCI6InRydWVfYml0cmF0ZSIsInZlcnNpb24iOm51bGx9LCJ0ZndfbGVnYWN5X3RpbWVsaW5lX3N1bnNldCI6eyJidWNrZXQiOnRydWUsInZlcnNpb24iOm51bGx9LCJ0ZndfdHdlZXRfZWRpdF9mcm9udGVuZCI6eyJidWNrZXQiOiJvbiIsInZlcnNpb24iOm51bGx9fQ%3D%3D&frame=false&hideBorder=false&hideFooter=false&hideHeader=false&hideScrollBar=false&lang=en&maxHeight=596.966px&origin=https%3A%2F%2Farquitecturaviva.com%2Fen&sessionId=2c445e90ceeab5df41e6db7160945615ce32d02b&showHeader=true&showReplies=false&siteScreenName=arquitect_viva&transparent=false&widgetsVersion=aaf4084522e3a%3A1674595607486"></iframe>
```

Comment: Same issue here. When You are logged on Twitter, you see correct timeline.

Comment: Seems to be a bug with the widget itself. https://twittercommunity.com/t/embedded-timeline-is-out-of-order-when-not-logged-in/201211

Answer (score 1):

It is due to change its X polices. For more details see here https://twittercommunity.com/t/embedded-tweets-not-working/199477/35?page=2

Comment: So it won't work anymore?
If so, why don't they eliminate the functionality?